# Restsharp using with openfire rest service

Tags: rest, json.net, openfire, restsharp

First I create json service like

```
RootObject ro = new RootObject ();
        ro.username = "halukmy";
        ro.password = "1234";
```

Than I create my rest post

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://84.84.83.82:9091" +
                         "/plugins/restapi/v1/users");
            client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator ("username", "haluk", "password", "123456789");
            var request = new RestRequest ("resource", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;



            request.AddBody (new RootObject {

                username = "ffff" +
                "",
                password = "1234"
            });

            client.Execute (request);
```

but I got header error? when I use on browser no problem but in c# code I get this error
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with the error you received?

Comment: ErrorMessage "Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers)" string

Comment: http://s21.postimg.org/6f8pdr4t3/Screen_Shot_2015_11_20_at_16_38_13.png this is full problem

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the:

```
request.AddHeader ("Accept", "application/json");
```

if you have:

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
```